# Learning GUI design: where do I start?

Tags: android, interface-design

I want to learn how to create stylish Graphic User Interfaces for android applications beyond the common style of the google apps itself. if some one has some documents i can read to give applications that particular style.

for example i like a lot the style of the QuizUp app, i would like to learn more about how they got this look.

Comment: Hi SoulrainX, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. As-is, your question is extremely broad and likely to be put on hold for that. Is there a certain part in the process you get stuck at where we can help, or do you just need some pointers where to start learning GUI design? Thanks!

Comment: some starting points in this particular topic will be appreciated, thank you.